# Weird sql insert after json decode function

Tags: php, mysql, json, decode

after decoding an jsonfile and inserting to mysql i get weird entry results into my database.
with the echo-function i get correct output for each of the variables $clanid. but inside the database i get always the number 2147483647 for each id-entry.
All the other variables and entries are fine.
does somebody has an idea what is happening here?

this is the code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxxx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

$url = "http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=&level=1&min=1&max=50&points=48000";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$in=$data['clanList'];
$results = $data['results'];
$i = 0;
while($i + 1 <= $results){
    $clanid = $in[$i]['id'];
    $clanname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$in[$i]['name']);
    echo "Clan ID: $clanid<br />Clan Name: $clanname <br /><br />";

    $clanplayerCount = $in[$i]['playerCount'];
    $clanwarswon = $in[$i]['warsWon'];
    $clanwarslost = $in[$i]['warsLost'];
    $clanwarstied = $in[$i]['warsTied'];
    $clanLocation = $in[$i]['clanLocation'];
    $clanlevel = $in[$i]['level'];
    $clanidcorrected = $clanid;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO activeclans(id, name, location, playercount, clanlevel, warswon, warslost, warstied)
    VALUES('$clanidcorrected', '$clanname', '$clanLocation', '$clanplayerCount', '$clanlevel', '$clanwarswon', '$clanwarslost', '$clanwarstied')";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql); //must pass the connection variable before the sql query.
    $i++;
}
```

this is the result after using the php-file:
http://bornhoffer.de/grab-active-clans-search.php

so.. the echo-results are fine..

but in the database i get these entries:

```
 2147483647 ARAB CHAMPIONS? United Arab Emirates    50  6   43  23  11
 2147483647 Emirates    United Arab Emirates    50  5   23  18  8
 2147483647 Kings Rock  International   49  7   106 59  26
 2147483647 MEGA EMPIRE International   49  5   50  40  14
 2147483647 NORTH 44    International   49  5   70  39  10
 2147483647 Quantum's Web   U.S. Virgin Islands 50  5   63  23  9
 2147483647 ??? ??????? International   50  6   166 19  6
```

any help would be much appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: show your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `activeclans` table please?

Answer (score 3):

You are using an `INTEGER` on your id column in the database, and the numbers in your json file are too big to put inside of it, you could switch your `id` column to `BIGINT`.

`2147483647` is the biggest `INTEGER` value in mysql I believe, all the numbers in your link http://bornhoffer.de/grab-active-clans-search.php are bigger than that.